# ELL new logo is different in achievements section

Tags: bug, design

The ELL new logo is not same in the Full site view and Stack Exchange android app of the **Achievements** section. Hope those are need to be a same logo.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/site-icon-on-ios-app-has-a-circular-background

Comment: Makes me want to go get an Android device.